# Using slope=0 technique to find most likely spherical shell

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, atomic-physics, hydrogen

In this PDF

http://riedo.gatech.edu/Teaching/Modern_Physics/hw/HW3_2010_MP_SOL.pdf

problem#1,
the instructor solves the question of which spherical shell
(what radius $r$)  has the greatest probability for the 3p
hydrogen electron to sit in.

I understand everything except the one step where she throws
out a factor of $r^4$.

The wave function for the 3p electron is:

$\dfrac{4}{(81 \sqrt 6)}(6 - r)(r)e^{-r/3}$

(I neglect the $a_0$ factors as, like other constants,
they would not affect the calculation of where the points
are where $d(probability\_of\_finding\_electron)/dr = 0$.)

Indeed the first steps are to throw out all unnecessary
factors:   we can dump all constant factors like $a_0$
and $81 \sqrt 6$  as well as the $4\pi$ in the spherical
shell surface area expression $4 \pi r^2$

I.e. the probability for each particular shell is

$(4 \pi r^2)(\Delta r) \cdot \Psi^{*} \Psi$

And dumping all the constant factors including $\Delta r$ leaves us with:

$r^2 [(6-r)(r)e^{-r/3}]^2$

=

$r^4 [(6-r)^2 e^{-2r/3}]$

as the expression to be minimized.

Now the instructor then throws out the $r^4$, saying
we can neglect solutions at $r=0$.

But doesn't this actually change the expression when
you take $d(probability\_of\_finding\_electron)/dr$?

In other words, the zeroes of:

$\frac{d}{dr}(r^4 [(6-r)^2 e^{-2r/3}])$

are different from

$\frac{d}{dr}([(6-r)^2 e^{-2r/3}])$?

Would you please tell me why it's okay to throw out
the $r^4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructor hasn't thrown out $r^4$. If you do the calculations properly you will get the desired result. What the instructor is telling is that while simplifying and taking commons out for $\frac{\text{dP(r)}}{\text{dr}}=0$ you get,$$(\text r^3)(6-\frac{\text r}{\text a_0})(f(\text r))=0$$which gives, $\text r=0$ and $6\text a_0$ from the first two terms. But these two values correspond to minimum probability positions as obtained from the expression for $\text P(\text r)$ by setting $\text P(\text r)=0$. So, **for maximum probability positions** the first two terms of the above equation cannot be zero as they are zero for minimum probability positions. Hence, you have to check the solutions from $f(\text r)=0$.

Comment: I worked through the full calculations and you are correct that it works.  I do not understand how you got  $\dfrac{6-r}{a_0}$  for $dP/dr$ because substituting $6a_0$  into the expression for  $dP/dr$ does not give 0.

Comment: Its $6-r/a_0$ when you put $6a_0$ in r you get 6-6=0

Comment: See I suggest you to go with easy mathematics. To find the roots go in a systematic way. Expand the expression and differentiate you will be left with a cubic equation after taking $r^3$ outside. $r^3$ gives one solution at 0 and the cubic equation will give you 3 solutions out of which $6a_0$ corresponds to a minimum probabilty position.

Comment: Your explanation makes more sense now.  I seem to have had a mental block.  Thank you for helping me break through it.

Comment: I am going to flag this as the chosen answer because although both yours and Gert's were equally helpful, according to StackExchange yours occurred slightly earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you cannot simply 'neglect' $a_0$ (as the *.pdf actually shows).

In some test books the following substitution is used: $\rho=\frac{r}{a_0}$, so the $a_0$ doesn't have to be 'carried around'.

As your expression for $P(\rho)$ is made of three factors, each factor can be evaluated for extrema individually. $\rho=0$ is an obvious minimum from the first factor, $\rho=\infty$ is another from the exponential term.

The middle factor is evaluated by deriving it to $\rho$, setting to $0$ and that gives:

$\frac{2}{3}\rho^2-10\rho+24=0$.

Or $\rho=3$ and $\rho=12$.

Since as $P(\rho)$ is highest for $\rho=12$, we find that the most probable radial position is $r=12a_0$.

Comment: You are saying that wherever the slope goes to zero for just the MIDDLE term gives you the zeroes of the whole 3 part thing put together.  I am a little hazy as to why you are sure of this, but when I work it out using everything I end up with $(4*36) + (-60+-24)\rho + (6+8)\rho^2 + (-2/3)\rho^3$, which gives the same points of slope=0 to be 0, 3, and 12.  Thanks for the perspective.

Comment: Look at it like this. $(x-1)(x^2-4)(x+3)=0$ has 4 roots: $x=1, x=2, x=-2,x-3$ because you can evaluate the roots of each factor. As long as $x$ has one of these values the left hand always yields $0$.

Comment: @a00 $\rho$=6 does give zero check properly.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  Although this is not terribly hard stuff, I was getting confused.  But it is true that you must take the derivative first before using the rule of  "analyzing the pieces for roots separately", because for example of $P(\rho) = r^{10}(6-r)$, the roots of $P()$ are 0 and 6, but the roots of $dP/dr$ are 0 and 60/11.

Comment: Gert, thank you for putting it in a way where I can see exactly what you mean, and clearing up the picture in my head.